# Why does my do while statement work this way?

Tags: c

This code works but I'm confused on how. I was writing this program for a class. I needed to only accept positive integers. I created a do...while loop to do so. My question is, why does this code only check the correct way when I have the or "||" in there and not the "&&". I would assume it would need to test both to make sure that it is taking in the correct integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


main()
{
  float i, number, sum=0;
  int k;
do
{
  printf( "Sumation Calculator\n" );
  printf( "Enter number: " );
  scanf( "%f", &number );
  k = number;
}while(number < 1 || k != number);

  while (i <= number)
  {
    sum = sum + i;
    i++;
  }
  
  
  printf( "The summation of %f is %f.\n", number, sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is poor.  If a value like `"1.0000000001"` is entered, it will save `1.0f` in `number`.  `while (i <= number)` is bad as `i` value is indeterminate.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yeah, if you're going to use this approach to check for integers while consuming floating point inputs, you'd want to use `%lf` and the `double` type (which isn't technically *guaranteed* to work, but works on every system I've ever used save one weird "all integer types are 64 bits" weirdo one), and you'd need to initialize `i` to `0`. Though frankly, it's probably saner to use `k` and have `i` and `sum` be integer types as well, unless the goal is to demonstrate floating point weirdness.

Comment: shanerig Do not use `k = number;`  to find the whole number portion of a `float`.  It is _undefined behavior_ when out of `int` range.   Use `truncf()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two requirements:

1. That the value be positive
2. That the value be an integer (no fractional/decimal component)

Your test needs to be true if you *need to ask again*, not if you have the correct value; testing for the correct value would involve two "positive tests" joined by `&&`, but you want to test for incorrect values, which means you want to reject if either "negative test" fails. You need to ask again if *either* condition is violated. If you test `number < 1 && k != number` that means "I need to ask again only if it's *both* not positive *and* non-integer", so `0` (which is not positive, but is an integer) would be accepted, as would `1.5` (which is not an integer, but is positive).

Testing `number < 1 || k != number` correctly says "I need to ask again if it's not positive *or* it's not an integer"; if it fails either criterion, you loop and ask again.

Comment: This actually answers the OP's question. The negation can be seen as an application of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 1):

Others have explain  OP's logic issue.

> why does this code only check the correct way when I have the or "||" in there ...

Code is not corrct with only that change.  It has too many problems - many of which can be identified by enabling all compiler warnings.

`scanf( "%f", &number);` will round numeric input text to a `float`, losing non-integer detection.

`k = number;` is *undefined behavior* when `number` is much outisde `int` range.

`i <= number` is bad as `i` is not yet assigned.

The return value of `scanf( "%f", &number )` is not tested for success.

Below is a more robust way to test for input of only positive integers.

---

> I needed to only accept positive integers.

Best to:

1. Read the line of text into a *string*.
2. Parse it as an integer with `strtol()`.
3. Test for range, etc.

---

```
char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0; 
  long value = strtol(buf, &endptr, 10);
  if (buf == endtpr) {
    puts("No conversion");
    continue;
  }
  if (errno) {
    puts("Out of long range");
    continue;
  }
  if (*endptr != '\n') {
    puts("Non-numeric trailing junk");
    continue;
  }
  if (val < 0) {
    puts("Only positive values");
    continue;
  }
  // Success, now do something with val
}
```

This will fail input like `"123.0"` or `"1e2"` - which are both whole numbers.  Additional code could handle most of those cases.

Comment: Considering the scope and purpose of this exercise, it'd be enough to check return value of `scanf` and exit if <1.

Comment: @hyde For OP it may be.  Yet for someone else looking how to test for only positive integer input, OP's approach has many holes and a more robust method is deserved.

Comment: Well, this doesn't really handle overlong lines, so to make it robust, it needs a bit more work (like using POSIX `getline` or a re-implementation of that for pure standard library use).

Comment: @hyde Agree'd. I'd also make it a seperate help function.

Answer (score -1):

```
do
{
  ...
  k = number;  // now k == number
} while (number < 1 || k != number);

} while (number < 1 || FALSE);
} while (number < 1);
```

As you see the condition is not needed.

What is the initial value of `i`?

By the way it is "Summation" I believe.

Comment: Doing `k = number` doesn't guarantee `k == number`, as `k` is an `int`, and `number` is a `float`; if `number` has a decimal component, it'll be truncated and the two won't be equal. (There's also the pedantic bonus weirdness where even if both were `float`, `nan` wouldn't be equal to itself)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree, here one could and should not have used `float`.  However parsing a small number without decimals will work for `k == number` and describes the state viewed by the OP: `||` works, `&&` not - an other conceptual problem. Explaining floats was too much IMHO if or/and already poses a problem.